# Shrink clickable area on javafx buttons

Tags: button, javafx

I am using javafx and I do not know how to set the clickable area of a button so it would fit it's borders. Now the clickable area of the "Exit" button is overlapping the login button because of the shadows. I know I could move the buttons away from each other to avoid the overlap but in most cases in the app this is not possible.

[image: Clickable area]

This is my global.css code:

```
.button {
  -fx-background-color: white;
  -fx-label-padding: 5 20 5 20;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-border-color: black;
  -fx-border-width: 0.5px;
  -fx-border-radius: 35;
  -fx-cursor: hand;
  -fx-min-height: 40;
  -fx-max-height: 40;
  -fx-background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.9);
  -fx-background-radius: 35;
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 12, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
}
.button:pressed {
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 12, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
}
.button:hover {
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 12, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

And I'd like to have it like this (or even exactly on the borders, whatever is possible):

[image: Wished clickable area]

Here is my JFXButtonTest.java content:

```
package org.test.button;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.net.URL;
public class JFXButtonTest extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
      VBox pane = new VBox();
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      setCss(scene);
      stage.setMinHeight(300);
      stage.setMinWidth(300);
      stage.setTitle("Button test");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      JFXButton login = new JFXButton("LOGIN");
      JFXButton exit = new JFXButton("EXIT");
      VBox vBox = new VBox(login, exit);
      pane.getChildren().add(vBox);
      stage.show();
  }
  public void setCss(Scene scene){
      String resourceName = "/global.css";
      URL resource = JFXButtonTest.class.getResource("/global.css");
      if (resource!=null) {
          String s = resource.toExternalForm();
          scene.getStylesheets().add(s);
      } else {
          System.err.println("Resource "+resourceName+" not found!");
      }
  }
}
```

And the pom.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ButtonShadowTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Create and post a [mre]

Comment: Whoever needs minimum reproducable example don't know how to answer this. But I will add it for the sake of the rules, even though everything needed is there.

Comment: I don't know how to answer it, but I had some ideas. It's a lot easier (and less time-consuming) to test out some ideas if I don't have to write a bunch of boiler-plate code on your behalf. If that's your attitude to people who are trying to help you, I'm not going to waste my time.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Though I probably should have done.

Comment: What if you set the button's `pickOnBounds` property to `false`?

Comment: pickOnBounds just changes the bounds based on the shape. If I have circle and shadow around it, the clickable area still includes the shadows but is not clickable in the "corners" where square button would be.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found some sort of solution. It is a start but it will have to be extended for your needs.

First create CustomButton class:

```
package org.test.button;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomButton extends StackPane {
    @FXML private JFXButton button;
    @FXML private Rectangle clickArea;

    public CustomButton(String text) throws IOException {
        LFXMLLoader.loadRoot("/CustomButton.fxml", this);

        //make clickable area 5 pixels smaller
        clickArea.widthProperty().bind(button.widthProperty().subtract(5d));
        clickArea.heightProperty().bind(button.heightProperty().subtract(5d));
        clickArea.setOnMouseEntered(event -> button.fireEvent(event));
        clickArea.setOnMouseExited(event -> button.fireEvent(event));
        clickArea.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            button.getOnAction().handle(null);
            button.fireEvent(event);
        });
        button.setText(text);
    }

    public final void setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> value) {
        button.setOnAction(value);
    }
    public final EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnAction() {
        return button.getOnAction();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        button.setText(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return button.getText();
    }

    public final ObservableList<String> getButtonStyleClass() {
        return button.getStyleClass();
    }
}
```

Then CustomButton.fxml should be created (in resources folder if you are using maven, otherwise just adopt to your needs):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<fx:root fx:id="main" type="StackPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <JFXButton fx:id="button" mouseTransparent="true"/>
    <Rectangle fx:id="clickArea" fill="#00000000" styleClass="clickable" />
</fx:root>
```

I also created class LFXMLLoader to load the fxml:

```
package org.test.button;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LFXMLLoader {
    public static void loadRoot(String fxml, Object controller) {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(controller.getClass().getResource(fxml));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(controller);
        fxmlLoader.setController(controller);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally use it like this:

```
package org.test.button;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JFXButtonTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        setCss(scene);
        stage.setMinHeight(300);
        stage.setMinWidth(300);
        stage.setTitle("Button test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        VBox vBox = new VBox(new CustomButton("LOGIN"), new CustomButton("EXIT"));
        vBox.setSpacing(5);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(3));
        pane.getChildren().add(vBox);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void setCss(Scene scene){
        String resourceName = "/global.css";
        URL resource = JFXButtonTest.class.getResource("/global.css");
        if (resource!=null) {
            String s = resource.toExternalForm();
            scene.getStylesheets().add(s);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Resource "+resourceName+" not found!");
        }
    }
}
```